# template engines are tricky

Tags: pug, template-engine

after learning html css and js i move on to node to discover i need to learn how to use pug template engines which is much harder than normal html code
is there any package or anything that directly converts my html code to a template engine

```
        main
            .grid
                each product in prods
                    article.card.product-item
                        header.card__header
                            h1.product__title Great Book
                        .card__image
                        .card__content
                            img(src="images/book.jpeg", class="image" alt="")
                            h2.product__price $19.99
                            p.product__description A very interesting book
                        .card__actions
                            button.btn Add to Cart
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that:  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you done a web search for "html to pug"?

Comment: yeah.. i just realised that sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug isn't that much difficult once you get familiar with it's syntax. For Converting HTML code to pug
1.) Install **npm** package **html2pug** `Link-https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pug`

2.) You can use **various converters available on internet** which you can find just by entering html to pug converter on Google.`Example- https://html-to-pug.com/`

3.)But if you use **Vs code** there are certain extensions one such which is easy to use is :-
**Convert HTML to Pug by ditto** which you can find by searching in vs code extension market place.

```
Link -https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ditto.convert-html-to-pug
```